# How change connection of socket.io depend of the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am new on this, I have a socket client connection I want to change depending on the server I am using it, I have two,  one is the developer server and the other is the production server how I can change de connection It depends on which my code is?

this I have so I change before commit and push to the production server manually

```
var host = 'http://233.88.98.70:8080'; // local
// var host = "https://miserverprduction.com:10800" // prod

// create intance and connect sockets
var socket = io.connect(host, {
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
    reconnectionAttempts: 9999,
});
```

Is any solution for do it automatic?

Comment: Many modern frameworks support "environments" that capture if you are in production or development. You an implement the same using global variable that is set at runtime to either `development` or `production`, then simply query that variable and set the URI accordingly.

Comment: sorry, I am very new in this can you give to me an example of that coding?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you mean, but you could have a toggle on your front-end..

For reading ENV variables and using those when hosting, we would need to know what webserver you're using.. But for educational purposes..

using localStorage for example..

```
localStorage.setItem("mode", 'local');

var host = 'http://233.88.98.70'; // local
var mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
if(mode === "PROD"){
  host = "https://miserverprduction.com:10800"
}
```

Then you can have a toggle on your front-end OR you could manually assign it to production for exmaple :

`localStorage.setItem("mode", 'PROD');`

**NOTE : But this would be acceissible for the user also.. So probably should be avoided!**